# Use site theme elements in emails sent by workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2012, theme

I am creating a SharePoint 2010 workflow in Visual Studio 2012.  I would like to use colors and fonts from the site's theme to style the emails.  Because the customers may change the site theme, I'd like to pull the information from the site's active theme rather than hard-coding the values into the email.

How do I access the site's theme and retrieve the font names, sizes, and colors of various theme elements?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out that I could retrieve the `ThmxTheme` object from the current site.  As long as the customer was using a theme, any theme, it would exist and have the information I needed.  However, if the customer used the "default" or no theme, this would be null, in which case I just guessed at the appropriate style elements.

```
    private string _emailCSS = null;
    private string EmailCSS
    {
        get
        {
            if (_emailCSS == null)
            {
                ThmxTheme theme;
                string themeForWeb = ThmxTheme.GetThemeUrlForWeb(WorkflowProperties.Web);

                string fontFamily;
                string color;
                string backgroundColor;
                string accentColor;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(themeForWeb))
                {
                    // default values if site has no theme
                    fontFamily = "Verdana, sans-serif";
                    color = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.Navy);
                    backgroundColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.LightGray);
                    accentColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.Blue);
                }
                else
                {
                    // use theme colors for emails, if site has a theme
                    theme = ThmxTheme.Open(WorkflowProperties.Site, themeForWeb);
                    fontFamily = theme.MinorFont.LatinFont;
                    color = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(theme.DarkColor1.DefaultColor);
                    backgroundColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(theme.LightColor2.DefaultColor);
                    accentColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(theme.HyperlinkColor.DefaultColor);
                }
                _emailCSS = string.Format(@"
    BODY {{
        font-size: small;
        font-family: {0};
        color: {1};
        background-color: {2};
    }}
    P {{
    }}
    .folio {{
        color: {3};
    }}
```

"
                               , fontFamily
                               , color
                               , backgroundColor
                               , accentColor
                           );
                }
                return _emailCSS;
            }
        }